# R programming, I need to find the expected amount of draws it takes to get three certain letters in a sample using monte carlo sim

Tags: r

For example, I need to find the total amount of draws it takes to pull A , B, and C from a sample.

So far I used the `which()` method to help find what positions it appears in the output, but I dont know how I would go from there.  we are told the answer is around 20.25.  I know how we can do it with only one letter to find (answer is around 13 for one letter), but I don't know the proper way to find multiple letters.

my code:

```
draw <- function(){

letters <- sample(LETTERS)


which(letters == "A")


#print(letters)
#print(which(letters == "A"))
#print(which(letters == "B"))
#print(which(letters == "C"))


}

mean(replicate(10000, draw()))
```

Comment: You're not far off. If you want to find out how many draws it took for each sample to get all of A, B and C you need to combine the three `which`es somehow.

Comment: I did try  `which(letters == "B") & which(letters == "C") & which(letters == "A")` before but I got 1 output

Comment: `which` is returning the position in the sample. I.e. if `A` is the 5th letter chosen you get `5` back. You want to know how many letters chosen before you've got all 3 letters, which is the same as one of the three which values...

Comment: I am still lost... do i save each which to a variable and then add them?

Comment: You might start with Position(function(x){x=="A"},x), which will give you the first location where (for instance) A occurs.  Then if you simulate a long chain of values, you can get your answer from the three Position() functions.

Comment: You want the highest of the three `which` values, as that is how many draws it took to get all three letters.

Answer (score 0):

Continue sampling 3 letters until you get the required letter combination and return the count of draws that it took to get the combination required.

```
draw <- function(){
  vec <- c('A', 'B', 'C')
  count <- 1
  tmp <- sample(LETTERS, 3)
  while(!all(tmp %in% vec)) {
    tmp <- sample(LETTERS, 3)
    count <- count + 1
  }
  return(count)
}
```

You can use `replicate` to repeat this `n` times and get the mean.

```
mean(replicate(10000, draw()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

```
draw <- function(){

letters <- sample(LETTERS)

a <- which(letters == "A")
b <- which(letters == "B")
c <- which(letters == "C")

select <- c(a,b,c)

max(select)

}

mean(replicate(10000, draw()))
```